# How to configure basic authentication for SOCKs Proxy

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using Apache HttpClient 4.2.3 library for for accessing resources via HTTP/HTTPS. Requests are sent through SOCKs proxy which requires 'basic authentication'.

I looked at the API doc and found that there is class ProxyAuthenticationStrategy, which looks like serves the purpose.

But I am not able to figure it out how to use it. Specifically I am not able to find how to provide proxy credentials to ProxyAuthenticationStrategy.

I looked at the documentation & searched over net but could not find appropriate help over this topic.

Can someone please guide me on how to configure basic authentication for SOCKs Proxy?

Note: I am successfully able to communicate using Apache HttpClient 4.2.3 library through SOCKs proxy without authentication.

Thanks,
Sachin

Answer (score 0):

SOCKS is a TCP/IP level proxy protocol. It has nothing to do with HTTP and is out of scope as far HttpClient is concerned. HttpClient can be configured to connect all network sockets it creates via a SOCKS proxy but it will make no attempt to provide any user credentials to the SOCKS proxy.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. 

Is there any custom way to achieve this functionality ? 

Regards, 
Sachin